# I want to find the difference between two fraction numbers

Tags: python, function, fractions

**I want to find the difference between two fraction numbers.**

> I created a port of code but somehow it doesn't give right output and I don't know where is the problem

```
def findGCD(a,b):
    while b>0:
        r=a%b
        a=b
        b=r
    return a

def min_frac(num1,den1,num2,den2):
    den = den1 * den2
    num = num1*den2 + den1*num2
    gcd = findGCD(den,num)
    if gcd != 1:
        den *= gcd
        num *= gcd
```

Comment: You are adding, not subtracting.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Since you want to find the difference, `num1*den2 + den1*num2` should be `num1*den2 - den1*num2`.

(2) You need to divide both `den` and `num` by `gcd`, not multiply.

(3) You need to return `num` and `den`, otherwise you don't see the output.

```
def min_frac(num1,den1,num2,den2):
    den = den1 * den2
    num = num1*den2 - den1*num2
    gcd = findGCD(den,num)
    if gcd != 1:
        den /= gcd
        num /= gcd
    return num, den
```